# REGEX at last one uppercase and one number

Tags: php, regex

I searched everywhere but i couldn't find the right regex for my verificaiton

I have a `$string`, i want to make sure it contains at last one uppercase letter and one number. no other characters allowed just numbers and letter. is for a password require.

```
John8 = good
joHn8 = good
jo8hN = good
```

I will use `preg_match` function

The uppercase and letter can be everywhere in the word, not only at the begging  or end

Comment: How about instead of trying to combine it into one mega awesome regex you break it down into two? This way if your verification schematics change it will be easier to add/remove your requirements

Comment: I presume the order is not determined, so to complement @Newbi3 I would split in 3 regex, searching for uppercase, lowercase, and numbers.

Comment: I was just about to comment that you probably want at least one lowercase letter, but @Niloct beat me to it. You will need 3 separate checks, each one for 1 or more `[A-Z]`, 1 or more `[a-z]`, and 1 or more `[0-8]`. If you change your requirement to 2 or more of any, I think you will have to extract all of that class and count them.

Comment: Please, say when end to edit... (ex. 'jo8hN' is valid or not?)

Comment: @PeterKrauss is valid. i done to edit. the uppercase and letter could be anywhere in the word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, but is a bit of a mess. Consider using multiple checks for readability and maintainability...

```
preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]*([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*\d|\d[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]*$/', $password);
```

Comment: Just wondering why you need to do this in 1 regex? Something like that is next to impossible to maintain...

Comment: Considering i have to use this many times in my web applicaiton,i want to create a function where to load all this from an config file. so whenever i want to change something, just edit the config file, not all files where i applied regex. Do you think is bad ideea to use only 1 regex for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex pattrn

```
^([A-Z]+([a-z0-9]+))$
```

Preg_match

```
preg_match('~^([A-Z]+([a-z0-9]+))$~',$str);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dB6kC7)</kbd>

Comment: The uppercase or letter can be everywhere in the word, not only at the begin or end

Answer (score 0):

Your requisition need "precise syntax description", and a lot of examples for assert your description. Only 3 or 4 examples is not enough, is very open.

For last confirmed update:

```
preg_match('/^([a-z]*\d+[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*\d+[a-z]*)$/',$str)
```

### History

first solution `preg_match('/^[A-Z][a-z]+\d+$/',$str)`

After your edit1: `preg_match('/^[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*\d+$/',$str)`

After your comment about utf8: hum... add at your question the valid language. Example: "José11"  is a valid string?

After your edit2 ("jo8hN" is valid): and about number, can repeat?  Well I suppose not. "8N" is valid? I suppose yes.  `preg_match('/^([a-z]*\d+[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*\d+[a-z]*)$/',$str)`  you can add more possibilities with "|" in this regex.

Comment: Forgot that the first character can be lowercase. After edit, only accounts for one capital letter.

Comment: Yes utf-8 and the uppercase or letter can be everywhere in the word, not only at the begin or end

Comment: @PeterKrauss uhmm, how to explain more easy. I want the string to contain at last one uppercase and one letter. only numbers and letters allowed.
valid strings: joH8n , Jo8N, JOhn8